Proportion mediated possible for Binary outcome, Continuous mediator?
I am running a mediation analysis on a categorical X (race/ethnicity), binary Y (disease status), and ordinal M (can be any integer 0 - 10). N-controls = 1321. Ncases = 384. I conducted this analysis using Hayes PROCESS Macro for R, and specified dummy coding of X using the mcx function. For outcome M, linear regression was used. But for outcome Y, a logistic regression was used since it is a binary outcome.
I had calculated a percent mediated (ratio of the indirect effect to the coefficient of total effect). However, a reviewer stated that since the coefficients are from linear and non-linear logistic models, they would not be on the same scale, and therefore percent mediated may be problematic.
Upon my reading, I get conflicting information. I see that many epidemiological studies with a binary Y and continuous M have reported percent mediated. I have also seen that using a bootstrap method and having prevalence of disease >5% led to accurate percent mediated results. Conversely, in Hayes' book, he cautioned against using this percent mediated metric. However, he did leave room to say that if the sample size is at least 500, a percent mediated may be trustworthy.
So, for my sample of N = 1669 with a binary outcome and continuous M, would it be appropriate for me to calculate and report a percent mediated? All effects are in the same direction, and for levels of my X, all effects are significant.
If I am unable to report a percent mediated, would it be appropriate to simply conclude that there is "partial mediation" without any comment on the magnitude? This is of course in addition to proper reporting of mediation results, but I am imagining how to convey this information simply for an audience that may be unfamiliar with mediation analysis.
Thanks a lot.
